# how to use the same variable twice or use 2 different variables in ssis package ole db source editor or use 2 different variables

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I m trying to join two tables together and use the OLE DB Source in my SSIS package. I have two solutions here:

1. use the same variables twice in the query;
2. use two variables in the query.

I tried something like:

```
select     r.*, u.* 
from       recruiter r 
inner join users u on r.userid= u.userid 
where      r.modifieddate > ? 
or         u.modifieddate > ?
```

in my OLE DB Source Editor but apparently it's not working the way like Execute SQL Task. What should I do to make this right?

Comment: How did you map the variables?   How do you know it didn't work?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parameterized OLEDB source query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18288183/parameterized-oledb-source-query)

Comment: @TabAlleman cuz when I tried to map the variables it's saying not able to do that and ask me to use SQL Command with Variables

Comment: You mean it talks to you?   Or, if you mean it gives an error message, you can post the exact error message?

Answer (score 0):

Name your parameters in the mappings dialog 0 & 1.

[image]

[image]