# Cannot convert Date in SSIS Expression builder

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl, ssis-2012, sqldatatypes

*SSIS* expresion builder I have cast error cancnot convert `string` to `datetime`

```
"SELECT *
  FROM table Where OperatingDayDate>='"+@[User::MaxOperatingDayDateTime]
```

> ERROR : CANNOT CONVERT STRING TO DATETIME

MaxOperatingDayDateTime IS variable DATETIME in SSIS
OperatingDayDate is type DATE

Comment: If you press Evaluate in the Expression Builder, what SQL query is returned?

Answer (score 1):

You have to cast the variable data type:

```
"SELECT *
  FROM table Where OperatingDayDate>='"+  (DT_WSTR,50)@[User::MaxOperatingDayDateTime] + "'"
```

One thing not mentioned, if you are using the SQL command in OLEDB Source you can use parameterized query:

```
SELECT * FROM table Where OperatingDayDate >= ?
```

- [Parameterized OLEDB source query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18288183/parameterized-oledb-source-query)

Comment: @Yasirayub what have you tried? The first or second method?