# SSIS: Variable from SQL to Data Flow Task

Tags: sql-server, ssis, oledb, etl, sql-server-data-tools

Pretty new to BI and SQL in general, but a few months ago I didn't even know what a model is and now here I am...trying to build a package that runs daily.

Currently running this is Excel via PowerQuery but because the data is so much, I have to manually change the query every month. Decided to move it into SSIS.

Required outcome: Pull the last date in my Database and use it as a variable in the model (as I have millions of rows, I only want to load lines with dates greater than what I have in my table already).

Here is my `Execute SQL Task`:
[image]
[image]

I set up a variable for the SQL query
[image]

and trying to use it in my OLE DB query like this
[image]

`Execute SQL Task`: results, are fine - returns date as "dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss"

```
SELECT MAX (CONVACCT_CREATE_DATE) AS Expr1 FROM GOMSDailySales
```

`Variable for OLE DB SQL Query`:

```
"SELECT fin_booking_code, FIN_DEPT_CODE, FIN_ACCT_NO, FIN_PROD_CODE, FIN_PROG_CODE, FIN_OPEN_CODE, DEBIT_AMT, CREDIT_AMT, CURRENCY_CODE, PART_NO, FIN_DOC_NO, CREATE_DATE
FROM cuown.converted_accounts
WHERE (CREATE_DATE > TO_DATE(@[User::GetMaxDate],'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss'))
AND (FIN_ACCT_NO LIKE '1%')"
```

Currently getting `missing expression` error, if I add `" ' "` to my `@[User::GetMaxDate]`, I get a `year must be between 0 and xxxx` error.

What am I doing wrong / is there a cleaner way to get this done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the OLEDB source use the following, change the data access mode to **SQL command**, and use the following command:

```
SELECT fin_booking_code, FIN_DEPT_CODE, FIN_ACCT_NO, FIN_PROD_CODE, FIN_PROG_CODE, FIN_OPEN_CODE, DEBIT_AMT, CREDIT_AMT, CURRENCY_CODE, PART_NO, FIN_DOC_NO, CREATE_DATE
FROM cuown.converted_accounts
WHERE (CREATE_DATE > TO_DATE(?,'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss'))
AND (FIN_ACCT_NO LIKE '1%')
```

And click on the parameters button and map `@[User::GetMaxDate]` to the first parameter.

For more information, check the following answer: [Parameterized OLEDB source query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18288183/parameterized-oledb-source-query)

**Alternative method**

If parameters are not supported in the OLE DB provider you are using, create a variable of type string and evaluate this variable as the following expression:

```
"SELECT fin_booking_code, FIN_DEPT_CODE, FIN_ACCT_NO, FIN_PROD_CODE, FIN_PROG_CODE, FIN_OPEN_CODE, DEBIT_AMT, CREDIT_AMT, CURRENCY_CODE, PART_NO, FIN_DOC_NO, CREATE_DATE
FROM cuown.converted_accounts
WHERE CREATE_DATE > TO_DATE('" + (DT_WSTR, 50)@[User::GetMaxDate] +
"' ,'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss') AND FIN_ACCT_NO LIKE '1%'"
```

Then from the OLE DB source, change the data access mode the **SQL Command from variable** and select the string variable you created.

Comment: Need to use Alternative as parameters are not supported... But I run into "ORA-00933 SQL Command Not Properly Ended." errors when I try it like this.

Comment: At first glance it seems to work (completes with error, but it works like intended - if I run it again, it doesn't load anything). I will check my SSAS Model on Monday and come back if there are any issues. Thanks man!

Answer (score 1):

Your trying to use the SSIS variable like a variable in the query. When constructing a SQL query in a string variable you simply need to concatenate the strings together. The expression for your query string variable should look like this.

```
"SELECT fin_booking_code, FIN_DEPT_CODE, FIN_ACCT_NO, FIN_PROD_CODE, FIN_PROG_CODE, FIN_OPEN_CODE, DEBIT_AMT, CREDIT_AMT, CURRENCY_CODE, PART_NO, FIN_DOC_NO, CREATE_DATE
FROM cuown.converted_accounts
WHERE CREATE_DATE > " + @[User::GetMaxDate] +
"AND (FIN_ACCT_NO LIKE '1%')"
```

Comment: Firstly, thank you for the post edit.

Secondly, I get the following error: ORA-00933 SQL Command Not Properly Ended.

Could this be because there are no " ' " wrapped around my variable? I usually get this in Toad when I forget them...